# Using a for loop to sum

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a code to sum all the numbers in a vector from 100:40, but I am not allowed to use a sum function, only a for loop.

I've tried using a simple for loop, but get stuck trying to write the output command without a sum

```
for(i in 100:40)
{
print()
}
```

Comment: You can avoid `for` loop and use `Reduce("+",  100:40)`

Answer (score 3):

```
yoursum <- 0
for(i in 100:40){yoursum <- yoursum+i}
yoursum
# 4270
```